# Getting a list of objects with same id from two list of objects

Tags: python, list, object

Can anyone tell me an efficient way of getting a list of objects with same instance attribute say `id` from two different lists of objects?

I am doing something like this:

```
[_update_obj_properties(orig_obj, new_obj, columns) 
    for new_obj in new_objs for orig_obj in orig_objs 
        if orig_obj.id == new_obj.id]
```

but I feel this is not very efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ids are unique within each list, you could simply do this:

```
def to_dict(lst):
  return {obj.id : obj for obj in lst}

def unify_dicts(d1, d2):
  return [(obj1, d2[id]) for id, obj in d1.items() if id in d2]

objects_to_update = unify_dicts(to_dict(new_objs), 
                                to_dict(orig_objs))
for new_obj, orig_obj in objects_to_update:
    update_obj_properties(orig_obj, new_obj, columns)
```

Comment: why not use a dictionairy comprehension in `to_dict` ? Aka `return {obj.id : obj for obj in lst}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `_update_obj_properties` just once for each object, you have to break out of the looping after the condition is found to be `True` for the first time. This cannot be done in a list comprehension, so here is a normal for loop:

```
my_list = []
for new_obj in new_objs:
    for orig_obj in orig_objs: 
        if orig_obj.id == new_obj.id:
            my_list.append(_update_obj_properties(orig_obj, new_obj, columns))
            break
```

In you actually want to call `_update_obj_properties` for each matching pair of objects (and thus possibly multiple times for any given object), your list comprehension solution is the way to go.